# ipfs.add is not working

Tags: solidity, web3js, react, ipfs

I am trying to upload my file to IPFS and save its hash to my Ethereum contract but neither ipfs.add nor ipfs.files.add is working for me...
I have tried usin for loop i.e.

```
for await (const result of ipfs.add(this.state.buffer)) {
      console.log(result);
  }
```

and also this way:

```
ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (error, ipfsHash) => 
    {
      console.log('Trying to add');
      if(error) {
        console.error(error)
        return
      }
    })
```

but both of them are not working.... I've tried to debug my code but the control doesn't go beyond ipfs.add line....
Any help will be highly recommended as I am not able to find any help on the internet and stuck here badly from past few hours..

Answer (score 1):

`ipfs.add(fileUploaded)` works for me. buffer is not required. We can load the file directly.

I am using `"ipfs-http-client": "^50.1.2"` and `ipfs = create({ host: "ipfs.infura.io", port: 5001, protocol: "https" });`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `ipfs.add` with `ipfs.files.add`.

Comment: I have already tried using it but get this error: 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ipfs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.files.add is not a function
    at App.onSubmit

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm using ipfs-api version 18.1.1. If you cannot handle to make your code run you can try using ipfs-api, I'm using it for over 2 years now and I have hundreds of files uploaded to the IPFS via infura. Example: 
```const ipfsAPI = require('ipfs-api');
const ipfs = ipfsAPI('ipfs.infura.io', '5001', {protocol: 'https'});``` Now here you can access ```ipfs.files.add```

Comment: I have tried it as well... the error which I get on requiring ipfs-api is cannot find module... So I have installed ipfs-http-client...If try to upload it on infura the code doesn't show any error nor the control is passing from that piece of code... And if I try to upload on local daemon This Error shows up
"Access to fetch at ''http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: Of course you will get error for missing ipfs-api if you haven't installed it. Just open the console in the root of your project and fire ```npm install ipfs-api@18.1.1 --save-dev```. Then you can try my example.

Comment: I installed it before and installed it again using your npm command but still module not found error is showing up... I get few errors while installing ipfs-api and same was the case before...

Comment: `PS D:\eth-ipfs> npm install ipfs-api@18.1.1 --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated ipfs-api@18.1.1: ipfs-api has been renamed to ipfs-http-client, please update your package.json to get the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated promisify-es6@1.0.3: Unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated peer-info@0.11.6: No longer supported for js-libp2p0.28.0 or later
npm WARN deprecated libp2p-crypto-secp256k1@0.2.3: Included in libp2p-crypto, use it instead. https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p-crypto
npm ERR! code ENOENT      
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno ENOENT`

Comment: `npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/dignifiedquire/webcrypto-shim.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent`

Comment: I just created new testing project to make sure the ```ipfs-api``` package is still working and it is. Look at my JS file https://pastebin.com/sESqVHvv, I successfully uploaded file to IPFS right now. I think the problem is in your npm version. Try using mine npm version which is 6.9.0 and my nodejs version is 10.16.0

Comment: tried to downgrade my npm but still getting the same error :(